# ignore end part of log in grok

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am new with grok and logstash i have a log file which is separated with space like this

```
1477879888.908 728 486704579 TCP_REFRESH_UNMODIFIED/304 254 GET http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Index - HIER_DIRECT/91.189.88.162 -
```

i just want to filler my log for only this part and ignore other part

```
1477879888.908 728 486704579 TCP_REFRESH_UNMODIFIED/304 254 GET http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Index
```

ignore other part (i just want 7 space  separated data and ignoree other data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used this grok pattern.

```
%{BASE10NUM:number1}%{SPACE}%{INT:number2}%{SPACE}%{INT:number3}%{SPACE}%{WORD:msg}/%{INT:number4}%{SPACE}%{INT:number5}%{SPACE}%{WORD:protocol}%{SPACE}%{URI:action}
```

Input

```
1477879888.908 728 486704579 TCP_REFRESH_UNMODIFIED/304 254 GET http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Index - HIER_DIRECT/91.189.88.162 -
```

Output

```
number1     477879888.908
number2     728
port    
number5     254
number4     304
msg         TCP_REFRESH_UNMODIFIED
action      http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Index
protocol    GET
number3     486704579
```

You can then merge `msg` and `number4` to obtain a new field `tcpMsg`. Finally you remove `msg`, `number4` and `port`.

```
mutate {
  add_field => {
    "tcpMsg" => "%{msg}/%{number4}"
  }
  remove_field => ["msg", "number4","port"]
}
```

Hope this helps.